# Differences in TFS2017 build vs TFS2018 - Does MSTest version matter?

Tags: tfs, automation, tfsbuild, mstest

I recently started to work with TFS2018 instead of TFS2017.
I had a perfect build with my TFS2017 that used Test Agents.
From TFS2018 we don't have anymore Test Agents but Build Agents.
I managed to upload a Build Agent that run my tests but the tests which uses data source from the test in TFS Tests can't access the data and fail (It says that that the machine has a missing .Net Framework and to check in the machine.config but the machine.config has the .Net Framework provider. The coded test is connected to the test in TFS with Work Item and matching test number).
Tests that don't use data passes (the build works fine). 
Running the tests on local - All the tests passes (even those with data).
And I wonder - does TFS2018 not supports MSTest V1 anymore?
Can't believe that the Visual Studio version matters (2015).
Can't find the reason why the test would fail like this and it takes me out of my mind.
Any suggestion will help.

Comment: Tweaked the tags a bit to grab the right categories. MsTest V1 is still supported, but kind of considered deprecated apart from CodedUI and WebTest. The new MsTestV2 is the way forward: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/09/01/upgrade-to-mstest-v2/

MsTestV1 relies on .NET 2.0 and it's certainly possible that you would need to enable .NET 3.5 on the target machine for some tests to run.

It's also recommended to run install the 2018 Build tools and/or Visual Studio 2018 on the build server and not to rely on an older version if at all possible.

Comment: First of all - thank you very much. As far as I remember we work with .Net 4.5.2 because of internal infrastructure, so I guess it is not connected for the .Net version (as it worked with TFS2017). The move to MSTest V2 is a little bit hard for some reasons and we try to avoid it. What else can bring a build exception with .Net framework provider in machine.config (from connecting to data source!)

Comment: All I can assume is the .RunSettings file is not corrected. Maybe something about the legecy attribute? How else can I connect to data source via the .RunSettings file?